# How to fix failure parsing json using FullCalendar.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have question regarding on full calendar, I currently new for that, Why does my response shows. I currently getting the response from the url of my php file. I have module where I need to fetch all events on the calendar so I decided to use full calendar so right now I experience this error.

> message: "Failure parsing JSON"

I will share to you guys my code that I made.

**Front End:**

```
<script>

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

      var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid' ],
        defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
        defaultDate: '2019-06-13',
        header: {
          left: 'prev,next ',
          right: 'title',

        },
        events:'./Function/fetch_calendar_schedule.php',
        eventColor: '#008B74',
        eventTextColor: '#ffff'
      });

      calendar.render();
    });



</script>
```

**Back End:**

```
    <?php 
    require_once('../ConnectionString/require_db.php');
    session_start();

    $calendar_content = $db->prepare('SELECT event_name,event_start_date,event_end_date,link FROM tblevents')
    or die($db->error);
    $calendar_content->execute();
    $calendar_content->bind_result($title,$start,$end,$link);

    $result = array();
    while($calendar_content->fetch()) {
        //validate using user type where user redirect

        $result[] = array('title'=>$title,'start'=>$start,'end'=>$end,'url'=>$link);
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($result);


    }

?>
```

**Response Result:**

```
[{"title":"<strong>42nd Annual Convention <\/strong>\r\nSMX MOA\r\nNovember 15, 2019\r\nScientific Chairperson: Dr. Panaligan\r\nCoordinators: Dr. Rowena Zabat","start":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","end":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","url":""}][{"title":"<strong>42nd Annual Convention <\/strong>\r\nSMX MOA\r\nNovember 15, 2019\r\nScientific Chairperson: Dr. Panaligan\r\nCoordinators: Dr. Rowena Zabat","start":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","end":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","url":""},{"title":"Download Registration Form (PDF)","start":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","end":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","url":"http:\/\/www.psmid.org\/forms\/pdf\/42nd-annual-registration.pdf"}][{"title":"<strong>42nd Annual Convention <\/strong>\r\nSMX MOA\r\nNovember 15, 2019\r\nScientific Chairperson: Dr. Panaligan\r\nCoordinators: Dr. Rowena Zabat","start":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","end":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","url":""},{"title":"Download Registration Form (PDF)","start":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","end":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","url":"http:\/\/www.psmid.org\/forms\/pdf\/42nd-annual-registration.pdf"},{"title":"Independence Day","start":"2019-06-12 00:00:00","end":"2019-06-12 00:00:00","url":""}]
```

Comment: You're echoing the JSON every time through the loop. You should only do it once after the loop.

Comment: @Barmar thank you barmar, ok now, I put the json_encode outside the loop

Answer (score 0):

To solved to problem, I put the json_encode result outside the loop:

```
    <?php 
    require_once('../ConnectionString/require_db.php');
    session_start();

    $calendar_content = $db->prepare('SELECT event_name,event_start_date,event_end_date,link FROM tblevents')
    or die($db->error);
    $calendar_content->execute();
    $calendar_content->bind_result($title,$start,$end,$link);

    $result = array();
    while($calendar_content->fetch()) {
        //validate using user type where user redirect

        $result[] = array('title'=>$title,'start'=>$start,'end'=>$end,'url'=>$link);
        header('Content-type: application/json');



    }
    echo json_encode($result);
?>
```